# When are a female's eggs created?

Tags: human-biology, development, meiosis

Since a human woman is born with a set number of eggs, and meiosis is the process by which sex cells are produced, would meiosis in a woman happen before she is born or soon after she was born?

If meiosis creates sex cells and women are born with a set number of sex cells, when in the development of a woman are her sex cells created?

Comment: I can't understand your question.

Comment: @WYSIWYG If meiosis creates sex cells and women are born with a set number of sex cells, when in the development of a woman, are her sex cells created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oocytes, or immature female eggs, develop in the fetus's ovaries during pregnancy. This graph ([U. New South Wales](https://embryology.med.unsw.edu.au/embryology/index.php/Oocyte_Development#Oogenesis)) shows the oocyte population over time in a human female:

[image: graph of oocytes in human body]

Although the x-scale is kind of confusing (months when negative, years when positive), you can see that the fetus has all the oocytes it will ever have at the peak 18-22 weeks after conception. Since age 0 is birth, meiosis in a woman happens long before she is born.

Comment: Meiosis starts before birth but finishes after.